# How to get the table row values including the foreignkey table row values using core?

Tags: sqlalchemy

With two tables like this:

```
one_table = db.Table(
    "one",
    metadata,
    db.Column("id", db.Integer, primary_key=True),
    db.Column("name", db.String),    
)    

two_table = db.Table(
    "two",
    metadata,
    db.Column("id", db.Integer, primary_key=True),
    db.Column("name", db.String),      
    db.Column("one", db.ForeignKey("one.id")),
)
```

How can **core** (not ORM) be used to get all the data in the `two_table` with all the data from the corresponding fk? To get the spesific `two_table` row:

```
select(two_table).where(two_table.c.id == some_two_table_id)
```

I know this is basic SQL, but somehow I can't figure out how to do it with "core".

Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a query with a `.join()`

```py
query = db.select(
    one_table.c.id.label("one_id"),
    one_table.c.name.label("one_name"),
    two_table.c.id.label("two_id"),
    two_table.c.name.label("two_name"),
).join(two_table)
print(query)
"""
SELECT one.id AS one_id, one.name AS one_name, two.id AS two_id, two.name AS two_name 
FROM one JOIN two ON one.id = two.one
"""
```